# RetryTemplate with ServiceActivator and JdbcMessageHandler

Tags: jdbc, spring-integration

I am using spring integration to pull data from source into database.

`JdbcMessageHandler` is used to handle the db inserts,

Is it possible to attach to `ServiceActivator` to `RetryTemplate` (with ExponentialBackOffPolicy) in order to retry if there are db connection related errors?

tried this

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "DatabaseOutput", adviceChain = {"retryAdvice"})
public MessageHandler jdbcMessageHandler() {
    JdbcMessageHandler jdbcMessageHandler = new JdbcMessageHandler(getDataSource(),...);
}




@Bean
public RetryTemplate retryTemplate() {

    RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();

   ...

    return retryTemplate;
}

@Bean
public RequestHandlerRetryAdvice retryAdvice(RetryTemplate retryTemplate) {
    RequestHandlerRetryAdvice advice = new RequestHandlerRetryAdvice();
    advice.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate);
    return advice;
}
```

When I started the app, I gave it wrong host and expecting it to try n-times , where n is  `retryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(99)` that I set on  the `RetryTemplate`.

But instead it failed immediately

part of stack trace:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5431 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:319)
at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223)
at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:402)
at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:261)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:121)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:159)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:117)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:337)
at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DatabaseDriver.fromDataSource(DatabaseDriver.java:329)
```

after fixing the issue,  it keeps trying to connect endlessly.

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5431 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:319)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:402)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:261)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:121)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:159)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:117)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:646)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:691)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(JdbcTemplate.java:1034)
    at org.springframework.integration.jdbc.JdbcMessageHandler.executeUpdateQuery(JdbcMessageHandler.java:233)
    at org.springframework.integration.jdbc.JdbcMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(JdbcMessageHandler.java:175)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.ReplyProducingMessageHandlerWrapper.handleRequestMessage(ReplyProducingMessageHandlerWrapper.java:59)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler$AdvisedRequestHandler.handleRequestMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:208)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice$CallbackImpl.cloneAndExecute(AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.java:166)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice.lambda$doInvoke$1(RequestHandlerRetryAdvice.java:86)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:329)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:255)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice.doInvoke(RequestHandlerRetryAdvice.java:86)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.invoke(AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.java:67)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy190.handleRequestMessage(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.doInvokeAdvisedRequestHandler(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:155)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:139)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:457)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.doProduceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:325)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:268)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:232)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:142)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.invokeHandler(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:222)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.dispatch(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:178)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:216)
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.sendMessageIfAny(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:397)
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.access$300(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationBatchMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:550)
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationBatchMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:518)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeBatchOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2274)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeBatchOnMessageWithRecordsOrList(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2264)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeBatchOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2207)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeBatchListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2117)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeBatchListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2000)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1979)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeIfHaveRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1366)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1357)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1252)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:241)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:98)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:109)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:235)
    ... 84 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DatabaseDriver.fromDataSource(DatabaseDriver.java:329)

This has nothing to do with your `JdbcMessageHandler`. It fails much earlier than you try to send a message: on start up when Spring Boot tries to initialize data base via scripts. At the moment you just don't say to Spring Boot that you use a PostgreSQL, so it tries to resolve it via `DataSource`. Even if you would say it still will fail because Spring Boot won't be able to initialize DB with respective scripts.

Please, see if you can simulate some other error to let your application to pass down to message exchanges.

Comment: WOW, you are right! it actually failed on creating bean webMvcMetricsFilter-> prometheusMeterRegistry-> datasource ->DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Comment: I fixed the above, but now it keeps attempting without stopping. full stack in post.

Comment: I doubt that. It looks like the story is not about a `retryAdvice` on that service activator, but rather a `KafkaMessageListenerContainer` in the beginning of your flow. See if you can turn a DEBUG logging level on for the `org.springframework.retry` category to observe some activity from the `RetryTemplate`.  Another way is to set a break point in the `RetryTemplate` to investigate what is going on there when your `PSQLException` is thrown.

Comment: I am also using PollerMetadata bean can it be related ?

Comment: I put brakes point in RetryTemplate and looks like doExecute called multiple times, I guess Kafka keeps polling even if there is error writing... can I prevent this?

Comment: Correct. That may happen for different messages sent from `KafkaMessageListenerContainer`. What I mean is a break point somewhere in that `doExecute`  around `while (canRetry(` to see what is going on with a single message and how that `PSQLException` is handled here and so on.

Comment: The poller is not included in your stack trace: not sure why you mention it...

Comment: well, inside loop the number of retries matches that I set in RetryTemplate, it catches correct error: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5431 refused. Then it exits the loop calling 'continue' but then fail in  this.handleRetryExhausted(recoveryCallback, context, state); ( I am checking decompiled class)

Comment: looks like it keeps calling doExecute

Comment: So? This retry works well, but then when it is exhausted, an exception is thrown back to that `KafkaMessageListenerContainer` which probably does its own retry feature

Comment: See `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice.recoveryCallback` to handle that exhausted case. What is the point of this retry over here since in the end you just thrown exception back to Kafka and let it to retry its own way?

Comment: Yes, I also see that KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.sendMessageIfAny is invoked all the time. 
Can  prevent  kafkalistener   polling if serviceActivator is struggling?

Comment: Probably there are several options: you can `pause` that Kafka container from polling until the problem with service activator is solved. You can still call service activator for all he polled records, but use that `recoveryCallback` to sand failed messages somewhere else, but don't bubble exception back to Kafka to let it just commit this offset and go ahead with other records.

Comment: Already implemented recoveryCallback to log records somewhere, but Kafka still invokes (only one message in topic). The last doubt how to prevent error returning to kafkalistener?

Comment: If you use a `recoveryCallback`, then exception must not bubble back to Kafka container. Place breakpoint in the `RetryTemplate.handleRetryExhausted()` and see what is going on.

Comment: thanks. looks like works. Is it possible to set Retry Policy per type of error? e.g. if it's connection error then retry n times, if it's sql insert error don't retry just skip. I can create new question (tomorrow) if needed.

Comment: See different `RetryPolicy` strategy implementations.