# ServiceActivator use only one advice instead of 2 advices fro retrying and error filtering

Tags: spring-integration, spring-retry

Do I really need to define 2 advices over `ServiceActivator` (`RequestHandlerRetryAdvice`) if I need to use `RetryTemplate` (with `AlwaysRetryPolicy`) and  `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` where I filter the error that I don't want to retry on?

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "outboundChannel", adviceChain = {"retry", "filter"})
public MessageHandler handler() { 
    JdbcMessageHandler ...
}
```

This works fine, but why can't I do it within one place only?

Or I should override `canRetry` method of `AlwaysRetryPolicy` and do this form there?
I tired that (retuned false) but it caused some circular loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I said you before over here: [RetryTemplate with ServiceActivator and JdbcMessageHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75143424/retrytemplate-with-serviceactivator-and-jdbcmessagehandler)

> See different `RetryPolicy` strategy implementations

I think a `BinaryExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy` should meet your requirements:

```
 * A policy, that is based on {@link BinaryExceptionClassifier}. Usually, binary
 * classification is enough for retry purposes. If you need more flexible classification,
 * use {@link ExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy}.
```

You also can implement a custom `RetryPolicy` which would delegate to something like `BinaryExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy` but then do some some other logic according to the `SQLException` and its error code.

The `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice.recoveryCallback` may be used to deal with exceptions which were retries or not.

Comment: Yes, I just couldn't find correct cone, will try now BinaryExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy

Comment: Couldn't find enough documentation, how do I register Specific Exceptions with specific cause?

Comment: See `BinaryExceptionClassifier` and its `traverseCauses`. You also can use a `CompositeRetryPolicy` if you need to have several different strategies for different exceptions.

Comment: I think I did not explain correctly what I need, in case of SQLException, I want to filter only exceptions with  specific SQL error code(state).

Comment: So, you probably can implement a custom `RetryPolicy` which would delegate to something like `BinaryExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy` but then do some some other logic according to the `SQLException` and its error code.

Comment: ok almost got what I need in ` boolean canRetry` that I overridden in custom RetryPolicy, I am able to find the errors that I need. one I find I return `false` this causes the exception to propagate to `kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.setErrorChannelName` the source of flow. I don't see option to trap error in `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice`

Comment: maybe to add  advice.setRecoveryCallback and return null?

Comment: Why do you say that? See `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice.recoveryCallback`: when exception is not retriable we try to call a recoverer in the end. See `RetryTemplate` source code.

Comment: OK. I added some sentences to my answer.